# Query table names

Tags: python, postgis, query, psycopg2

I want to query a table in my PostGIS table named `Seg_060_2009` using psycopg2 and can't seem to get my query to execute.  The query will execute if I name the table `layer`.  Are there restrictions on table names?  How can I pass a variable to a SQL statement in Python?

This works:

```
import psycopg2

try:
    conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='postgres' user='postgres' host='localhost' password='daniel'")
except:
    print "I am unable to connect to the database"

print ("I connected to the database")

cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("select relname from pg_class where relkind='r' and relname !~ '^(pg_|sql_)';")
print cur.fetchall()

#
cur.execute("""SELECT * FROM layer Order By sed_class """)
```

but this won't:

```
import psycopg2

try:
    conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='postgres' user='postgres' host='localhost' password='daniel'")
except:
    print "I am unable to connect to the database"

print ("I connected to the database")

cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("select relname from pg_class where relkind='r' and relname !~ '^(pg_|sql_)';")
print cur.fetchall()

#
cur.execute("""SELECT * FROM Seg_060_2009 Order By sed_class """)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must enclose your table name in double quotes for PostgreSQL to recognize capital letters. --> "Seg_060_2009"

Comment: Yes, it works, but you should consider using only lower case in naming to reduce the need.